# Kadmin: Client not found

Tags: 16.04, active-directory, kerberos

I'm attempting to join ubuntu 16.04 LTS to a windows AD. My goal is for this client machine to be able to log in with the Windows AD username and be able to access the Windows shares.

I started by following these guides

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryWinbindHowto

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/Kerberos

help.ubuntu.com/community/Kerberos

I completed the Kerberos installation and am able to get the ticket with kinit.

```
$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
Default principal: administrator@MYDOMAIN.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
07/14/2017 15:08:25  07/15/2017 01:08:25  krbtgt/MYDOMAIN.COM@MYDOMAIN.COM
renew until 07/15/2017 15:06:23
```

I went back to the Samba/Kerberos guide to create the principle for the samba service but I am unable to use the kadmin command. I get the following error:

```
$ kadmin -p administrator/admin
Authenticating as principal administrator/admin with password.
kadmin: Client not found in Kerberos database while initializing kadmin interface
```

How come I can get the ticket with kinit yet I'm not able to use the kadmin command?

Comment: In general, we don't care which tutorials you say you have read and followed. We care about the exact commands you executed and their output, what you expected to happen, and what happened.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35333503/client-not-found-in-kerberos-database-while-initializing-kadmin-interface

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I read that page, but I think that only applies if I had a linux KDC running and not a windows AD. I installed the required software to run the kadmin.local command 'sudo kadmin.local -q "addprinc administrator/admin' but I still received an error "no such file or directory while initializing kadmin.local interface"

Comment: post the commands and output.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen `sudo kadmin.local -q "addprinc administrator/admin"
Authenticating as principal administrator/admin@MYDOMAIN.COM with password.
kadmin.local: No such file or directory while initializing kadmin.local interface`

Comment: run `kadmin.local -q "list_principals"

Comment: @bodhi.zazen `$ sudo kadmin.local -q "list_principals"
Authenticating as principal administrator/admin@MYDOMAIN.COM with password.
kadmin.local: No such file or directory while initializing kadmin.local interface`

Comment: you do know you have to change "MYDOMAIN.COM" to your kerberos domain name ?

Comment: Yes, I changed the domain for anonymity.